# Label Sent Bitcoin Transaction

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, command-line-options

Is it possible to add a label to a sent bitcoin transaction using the bitcoin-cli?

Comment: Duplicate? Labels and comments are separate fields... Duplicate of my own question?

Comment: Labels are for addresses, not transactions https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.17.0#label-and-account-apis-for-wallet. It's unclear what you mean by comment and how that's different than a label.

Comment: The answers to your other question cover this. The bitcoin-cli has documentation you can read to find out the answer to your question. Some actions, that are possible in principle, may not be supported by the software you are using.